# How to create a Map<String, List<String>> property in properties file that can be injectable using Spring's @Value

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How do I create a `Map<String, List<String>>` property in properties file that can be injectable using Spring's @Value?

Example code snippet in Properties java file

```
@PropertySource({"file:salesforce-service.properties"})
public class Properties {
    @Value("#{${student.hobbies}}")
    private Map<String, List<String>> hobbies;
}
```

Comment: @Turing85, thank you. but it has to be a Map<String, List<String>>. See my answer below :D

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, my question is different than the associate one. The question being asked is Map<String, String> while my question is Map<String, List<String>>.

Comment: Although I see it as a variation on a theme, I agree that this might not be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer and the example code snippet in properties file:

```
student.hobbies={indoor: 'reading, drawing', outdoor: 'fishing, hiking, bushcraft'}
```

Reference: https://stackabuse.com/the-value-annotation-in-spring/
section --> Injecting into Maps